# Do not display content in React native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ui-kitten

Below is my code : 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRiPj.jpg)

I integrated react-native-ui-kitten. I run sample app of UI Kitten then it's ok. But when I implement into my app ( with all sample ) then It not display and dont show data.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12xOm.jpg)

I'm using the same data from UI Kitten, but in my application its not show data. Blank.

How can i display data ? ( I implement Feed style from UI Kitten ).

Comment: It's hard to tell because you aren't posting all the code.  Also, are you receiving any warnings or errors?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are putting the component within a `View` that does not have a dimension. Give it a dimension (e.g set `flex: 1`) and you should be able to see your component.

Comment: i put it, but still not have nothing

Comment: can you try running the most basic example, like the one in here:https://akveo.github.io/react-native-ui-kitten/#/docs/quick-start/getting-started and tell me if you still can't see it?